# Making nested query in Sequelizejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, node.js, sequelize.js

I have three tables Order, OrderItem, and OrderItemCategory.
Relation are as follows:

```
Order.hasMany(OrderItem, {as: 'orderItems'})
OrderItemCategory.hasMany(OrderItem, {as: 'orderItemCategory'})
```

I want to do a sequelizejs query that gets all orders, then for each order, get all the order Items based on the order Id, and then for each order item, get the product category from OrderItemCategory table.

I am trying the following code but it doesn't work for me:

```
return orderModel.findAll({
     include[{
            model: models.orderItem
            as: 'orderItems',
            include: [{
                model: models.orderItemCategory,
                as: 'orderItemCategory'
                }]
            }]
        }).then(function(results){
            //...           
        });
```

It tells me OrderItem is not associated with Order. Any help?

Comment: OrderItem.belongsTo(Order);  ?

Comment: @Molda That didn't work for me. I added this relation and re-created my db schema, but I still get OrderItem not associated to Order. I can see the foreign key in OrderItem table.

Comment: @Molda It worked after all. Partly it was me adding 'as' in belongsTo and partly my schema relation for Order and orderItem had constraint set to false. Thanks for the help.